# Convert int to const char *

Tags: cocos2d-x

In this code:

```
this->_label = CCLabelTTF::labelWithString(number,"Artial", 32);
```

`number` is 5, but must be a `const char *`.

How can I convert `number` from an `int` to the required `const char *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only three-argument call listed [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html) is:

```
+ (id) labelWithString:  (NSString *)  string
       fontName:         (NSString *)  name
       fontSize:         (CGFloat)     size
```

That means `number` should *not* be an `int` but should indeed be a `const char *`.

If you want to populate it with the *string* `"5"` instead of the *integer* `5`, you'll need to convert it to a string first.

Depending on the language you're using, this could be something like:

```
char buffer[20];
sprintf (buffer, "%d", number);
```

(for C) or using something like stringstreams in C++.

Comment: I tried (char*)5 , but my application crashed after compiling

Comment: @Bandit, yes, it would. That's turning tha arbitrary number 5 into a pointer, _not_ something that will work well. See the update.